# Android Kotlin WebView NullPointerException

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I'm trying to setup a basic webview app, and I'm getting this error, I don't know much about android development, just trying to make something simple for testing.

```
package com.fabledBits.roll4init

import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient

class MainActivity : Activity() {
    private val webView: WebView? = null

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (webView!!.isFocused && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack()
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        title = "roll4init"

        val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView)
        webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        webView.loadUrl("http://google.com")

        val webSettings = webView.settings
        webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webSettings.domStorageEnabled = true
        webSettings.allowFileAccess = true

    }
}
```

The error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.fabledBits.roll4init, PID: 10810
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.fabledBits.roll4init.MainActivity.onBackPressed(MainActivity.kt:12)
        at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:3784)
        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2866)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:4090)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `onCreate()`, you have:

```kotlin
val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView)
```

This creates a *local variable* named `webView`, and that is what you are assigning your value to.

However, that has the same name as your nullable `webView` property. `onCreate()` will be populating the local variable, so the `webView` property is `null`.

You have two issues.

First, you are using `!!`. That says "I want to crash the app if the expression evaluates to `null`". Crashing the app is very user-hostile. *Never* use `!!` unless you are *absolutely* certain that you want to crash the app. Do something else, such as use a safe call (`?.`).

Second, you probably do not want that local variable, so change `val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView)` to:

```kotlin
webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView)
```

Now, you will be assigning a value to the property, for use from `onBackPressed()`.